# SQL Group by on empty column

Tags: sql-server, group-by, null

I have a query that has the following part:

```
    UNION ALL

------------------------ Stock from last monday ---------------------------
SELECT

 [Local SKU code] as [Item No_]
,0 as [qty forecast]
,0 as [qty sold]
,0 as [qty sold py]
,sum(Quantity) as [Stock from last monday]
,0 as [actual production (kg)]
,0 as [actual production (pcs)]
,'' as [Customer Group]
,navision
,year(rep_date) as 'year'
,month(rep_date) as 'month'
,Datepart(iso_week,rep_date) as 'week'
,0 as [Bill-to Customer No_]

FROM dw_current_stock_mon as curr_stock

group by 
 [Local SKU code]
--here i would need curr_stock.[Customer Group]
,navision
,year(curr_stock.rep_date)
,month(curr_stock.rep_date)
,Datepart(iso_week,curr_stock.rep_date)
```

My question is how can I include curr_stock.[Customer Group] in the group by clause ? It is not in the original table, it's just created in the select clause.
It is needed because I want to use union all and all my other tables haves this column.
Or is there any other way to get around this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as (SELECT
 [Local SKU code] as [Item No_]
,0 as [qty forecast]
,0 as [qty sold]
,0 as [qty sold py]
,sum(Quantity) as [Stock from last monday]
,0 as [actual production (kg)]
,0 as [actual production (pcs)]
,'' as [Customer Group]
,navision
,year(rep_date) as 'year'
,month(rep_date) as 'month'
,Datepart(iso_week,rep_date) as 'week'
,0 as [Bill-to Customer No_]

FROM dw_current_stock_mon as curr_stock)
    select --new field names
from cte
group by --new fields name
```

Comment: Thanks! This works very fine, but how can I use this in UNION ALL ?

Comment: I don't get a question. May you provide a little bit more details about. BTW you can use union all in the cte.

Comment: Ok, I solved everything now. Your answer was the key! Thanks again!